# Is there anyway to trigger a JS function in an external file included in the head of HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to trigger a ajax call on click of a button. However the JS file is included in the **head** of the HTML.

**external.js**

```
(function(global, $) {
  global.RP = domId => {
    return new RangePlayer(domId);
  };

  function RangePlayer(domId) {
    // var vidId = document.getElementById("vidId").innerHTML;

    $("#" + domId).wrap(`<div id="video-box">
            <div class="ctrl-box">
                <div class="controler">
                    <i class="fas fa-play-circle" id="playVid"></i>
                    <div class="dragger-case">
                        <div id="vid-range"><div id="v-range"></div></div>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <i class="fas fa-volume-up" id="ctrl-sound"></i>
                        <div id="vid-volume" style="display:none;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        `);
    $("#" + domId).addClass("video-dom");
    vid = document.getElementById(domId);

    vid.controls = false;
    vid.volume = 0.4;
    let vidProp = {};
    var startVid;
    vid.ontimeupdate = function() {
      // if (vidProp.start !== 0) {
      if (vidPos() >= vidProp.end) {
        vid.pause();
        vid.currentTime = vidProp.end;
        $("#playVid").removeClass("fa-pause-circle");
        $("#playVid").addClass("fa-play-circle");
        vidProp.mode = "off";

        $("#v-range").slider("value", vidProp.start);
        /*  $('#playVid').addClass('fa-play-circle');
                  $('#playVid').removeClass('fa-pause-circle');
                  */
      }
      $("#v-range").slider("value", vid.currentTime);
      /*  if (vidPos() <= vidProp.start) {
                 vid.currentTime = vidProp.start;
                $('#playVid').removeClass('fa-play-circle');
                 $('#playVid').addClass('fa-pause-circle');

             }*/
      // }
    };

    function vidPos() {
      return vid.currentTime;
    }

    $("#ctrl-sound").click(() => {
      $("#vid-volume").toggle();
    });

    $("#playVid").click(() => {
      if (vidProp.mode === "off") {
        vidProp.mode = "on";
        $("#v-range").slider("value", vidProp.start);
        vid.currentTime = vidProp.start;
        vid.play();
        $("#playVid").toggleClass("fa-play-circle fa-pause-circle");
      } else if (vidProp.mode === "on") {
        vid.pause();
        vidProp.mode = "pause";
        $("#playVid").toggleClass("fa-play-circle fa-pause-circle");
      } else if (vidProp.mode === "pause") {
        vid.play();
        vidProp.mode = "on";
        $("#playVid").toggleClass("fa-play-circle fa-pause-circle");
      }
    });
    vid.onloadeddata = function() {
      $("#" + domId).show();
      vidProp = {
        start: 0.001,
        end: vid.duration,
        mode: "on"
      };

      $("#vid-range").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: true,
        min: 0.01,
        max: vid.duration,
        step: 0.01,
        values: [1.5, vid.duration-1.5 ],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          $("#RPvidStart").val(ui.values[0]);
          $("#RPvidEnd").val(ui.values[1]);

          vidProp.start = ui.values[0];
          vidProp.end = ui.values[1];
          if (ui.handleIndex === 0) {
            vid.currentTime = ui.values[0];
          } else if (ui.handleIndex === 1) {
            vid.currentTime = ui.values[1];
          }
          $("#v-range").slider("option", {
            max: vidProp.end,
            min: vidProp.start
          });
          startVid = vidProp.start;
          var vidRange = [vidProp.start,vidProp.end];
          console.log(startVid);
          $.ajax({
            url: "/dashboard/storyboard/ajax/get_video_range/", // form action url
            type: "post", // form submit method get/post
            dataType: "json", // request type html/json/xml
            traditional: true,
            data: {
              range: vidRange,

            },
            success: function(result) {
              if (result.error) {
                alert.html(result.html).fadeIn();
                console.log(e);
              } else {
                alert.html(result.html).fadeIn();
              }
            }
          });
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
          vid.pause();
          vid.currentTime = ui.value;
          $("#playVid").removeClass("fa-pause-circle");
          $("#playVid").addClass("fa-play-circle");
          vidProp.mode = "off";
          $("#v-range").slider("option", {
            max: vidProp.end,
            min: vidProp.start
          });
          /* if (ui.handleIndex === 0) {
                         vid.play();
                     }
                     */
        }
      });

      $("#v-range").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        value: vidProp.start,
        max: vidProp.end,
        min: vidProp.start,
        step: 0.01,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          vidProp.mode = "pause";
          vid.currentTime = ui.value;
        }
      });
      $("#v-range").appendTo(
        $("#vid-range .ui-slider-range.ui-corner-all.ui-widget-header")
      );
      $("#vid-volume").slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        step: 0.01,
        value: 0.4,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          vid.volume = ui.value;
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {}
      });
      *$("#saveTrim").click(function(){
        console.log("saved");*
    });
    };


  }
})(window, $);
```

The external Js only works if included in head. Its a plugin. I want to trigger an ajax call when button with id="saveTrim" is clicked. I am currently sending start and end time of video when its changed but not on click of a button.

Comment: You can try the following snippet in javascript, if the file is included in header
$(document).on("click", '#saveTrim', function() {
    //Action here.
})

Comment: If you want to attach an event to an html element from a script loaded before it then you have to wait for it to render. Since you're using jquery use `$( document ).ready()`
Docs: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/